# reconstruct object functions retrieved from localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I'm using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to store and retrieve objects from  `localStorage`. However, it appears that `JSON.stringify` strips out the instance functions from the object. Thus, after `JSON.parse`, I can no longer call `myObject.doSomething()`. I know that I can attach this function manually: `myObject.doSomething = MyClass.prototype.myFunction`, but that'll be troublesome if this action is repeated many times in the web app. How do people normally do this in JavaScript?

Comment: `localStorage` does allow you to keep Objects as values, keys should be strings. Is there any specific reason you want to store them as Strings?

Comment: the only reason is that I read somewhere on this site saying that most current browsers support only strings for localStorage, although the specs say they should support object. Is this true?

Comment: I've just tested with Chrome, the object retrieve from localStorage is just `[object Object]`, what can I do to restore its type? I tried calling its instance methods and properties but they are undefined.

Comment: I see, I was mistaken. Sorry for the confusion. `localStorage` is just calling `toString` method on the values and storing them as Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON obviously does not hold onto the functions themselves is only stores simple typed variables.  The way I have addressed this in the pass is to be a restore method in my class and simply call that method with the data from JSON so as to re-populate the class with the data that belongs in it.

I have done this extensively with the Value Object ( VO ) design pattern in my code base and it has worked quite well for me.  Just a word of a caution though, Ie7/Ie8 are not terribly friendly with this approach if you try to communicate across windows.  As I recall I think it is IE7 that does not return the right "typeof" for some properties so I ran into a whole bunch of challenges in my restore when cross-window communication was involved.

Comment: So I guess there's no elegant way to do this in JS then? I'll wait for a couple of days more to see if anyone else come up with any different suggestion before marking this as answer...